# Is possible to use wave guide to decrease beam width?

Tags: power, digital-logic, antenna, gain, waveform

If I use a normal 1/4 monopole antenna "30 MHz for example" and cover it with metallic wave guide has a narrow beam width, should the gain increasing according to this formula below?

$$G = 10 \; log \Big(\dfrac{32400}{H \times V}\Big)$$

[image]

Comment: That won't work as a waveguide. It will just shield the antenna.

Comment: why ? should be from dielectric material instead of metal ?

Comment: Waveguides are conductive and usually rectangular. A 30 MHz waveguide will be huge, and that antenna won't couple to it properly.

Comment: To visualize what a wave guide should look like - people use Pringles cans as a WiFi wave guide.

Comment: @Leon Heller how to calculate wave guide size against gain at this band ?

or how much it would be huge ?

Comment: Try Google. You will find plenty of design information. A waveguide doesn't provide gain, BTW.

Comment: Stacking multiple elements vertically it is the common practice to narrow the v.beamwidth. So with proper arrangement of -say- 4 monopoles with ground  plane, the beamwidth will be approx.5 degr in elevation plane.

Comment: Why is this tagged "digital-logic" ?

Comment: @ GR Tech  how you  calculated it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule of thumb: physically larger antennas have narrower beam width for the same frequency.

If you want to make a 30 MHz monopole more directional, you can't just cover it with a piece of metal.  One solution would be to get a bunch of antennas and build a linear array, where the array factor would give you the gain.  This array will need to be at least several meters long.  Adding a reflector behind the antenna would increase the gain a little bit, about a factor of two.  Bottom line, if you want a high gain at 30 MHz, you're going to need a REALLY big antenna.

Comment: how much big ? & how to calculate its big ?

Comment: Yagi beam antennas on the 10m amateur band are common.  They aren't small, but they are a lot smaller than those for 80 meters!

Answer (score 1):

An RFantenna does not produce a proper EM radiating field up close to the antenna. Fact of life I'm sorry to say. What it does produce up close is an E field and an H field that are more akin to that measured near to an inductor or capacitor. Up close, the two fields have not managed to become in time phase with each other and, as a pair of fields they cannot be described as a regular EM Field. This starts to occur at about 1 wavelength distant from the antenna.

Therefore, up close, a waveguide is useless apart from the fact that the other end of  the waveguide is not fit for propagating an EM field even if it had managed to concentrate all the up close antenna energy.